# (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 58P01 (undefined_file)

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

> `**` (Postgrex.Error) `ERROR 58P01` (undefined_file): could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.5/share/postgresql@9.6/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

I'm getting this error when I try to run `mix ecto.migrate`...

Why is it looking at that path? I've tried moving postgis.control

If I run this command `find /usr -name postgis.control` it gives me this result:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgis/2.4.0_1/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control
/usr/local/share/postgresql@9.6/extension/postgis.control
```

Does anybody know how I can move postgis.control or what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `postgis.control` should be in the `extension` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL share directory. You can find out the location of the share directory by running `pg_config --sharedir`.

All the other files that belong to the PostGIS extension must also be in place: the SQL files in the same directory as the control file, and the shared libraries in `pg_config --libdir`.